# Where is Doc Root

Tags: php

When I run this code on my localhost

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo "Doc root : $root <br />";
```

it responds with:

```
Doc root : C:/wamp/public_html/
```

When I run the same code on my remote server it responds with:

```
Doc root : /home/setine5/public_html
```

Notice that it does not have a trailing "/"

I'm trying to find a way to reference the same piece of PHP on both my localhost and remote server but cannot because of the missing forward slash.

How is this done normally?

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673097/where-to-set-php-serverdocument-root-trailing-slash)

Comment: Dave - What is it that I'm looking at?

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = sprintf('%s/', rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/'));` from the comment, this ensures that it will always have a trailing `/`.

Comment: Cool.  That what I was hunting for AND it works

Answer (score 1):

You can not say in advance if `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` contains a slash at the end or not. It varies according to the environment. In most cases, it doesn't have the trailing `/`, but in Windows, a trailing slash will cause issues.

The solution here, as Dave suggested, would be to append the trailing slash if it doesn't exist.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = sprintf('%s/', rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/'));
```

An alternative solution:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .= (substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], -1) == '/')?'':'/';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if it answers your question! :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to not use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to specify your files location. But use `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__) // For PHP version < 5.3` in your front controller to determine where it is located and then use relative to your front controller paths to files.

It will be more intuitive and understandable. This practise is used in many great frameworks and CMSs.